# Express "Cannot GET /query" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

i recently tried to work with *Express* and i find it kind of difficult, i tried defining routes in `app.js` file and after `require` to `index.js` and i still get this error when i try to browse to `localhost:3000/route`

the **query.js** file

```
exports.show = function(reg,res){
    res.render("test",{title:"query testing"});
};
```

i tried this in `app.js`

```
app.get('/query',require('./routes/query.js'));
```

and in `index.js`

```
var queryX = require('./query.js');
app.get('/query',queryX.show);
```

i tried the example with `route-separation` on github and i get an error to that too
why i can't get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look closely in the example: [Line 7](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/route-separation/index.js#L7) and [Line 21](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/route-separation/index.js#L7).

app.js:

```
var site = require('./routes/site.js');
app.get('/', site.index);
```

routes/site.js:

```
module.exports = function(req, res) { ... };
```

If you want to use routes/index.js to store all your routes you'll have to pass `app` to an exported function.

something like:

app.js:

```
var express = require('../..')
  , app = express();

require('./routes')(app);
```

routes/index.js:

```
var more_routes = require('./more_routes');

module.exports = function(app) {

  app.get('/', function(req, res){...});
  app.get('/show', more_routes.show);
  app.get('/list', more_routes.list);
}
```

Comment: thanks i used the second example and it worked, it looks that the examples miss mentioning some information or are outdated.